# REACT Router V6 cannot render Router inside another Router

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom@6.0.0-beta.0

I'm using nested Routes, I only have  once in my app.js but somehow I still get the error "ou cannot render a  inside another . You never need more than one".

app.js:

```
const App = () => {
const [chamber, setChamber] = useState("")
//initialise array of present speakers
const [members, setMembers] = useState([])

return (
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={
                    <ChamberSelector setChamber={setChamber} />}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="presence" element={
                    <PresenceList members={members} setMembers={setMembers} chamber={chamber} />}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="body/*" element={
                    <BodyColumns members={members} chamber={chamber} setChamber={setChamber} />
                }>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
)
```

}

BodyColumns.js:

```
    return (
    <section>
        <Navbar chamber={chamber} setChamber={setChamber} />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/sl" element={<RenderSpeakerList />} />
            <Route path="/cte" element={<RenderCTE />} />
            <Route path="/os" element={<RenderOS />} />
            <Route path="/id" element={<RenderID />} />
        </Routes>
    </section>

)
```

}

(none of the rendered elements refer to the Router).

Is this still a bug in this beta version of react router 6 or am I doing something wrong causing  to re-render inside the Router?

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with the states in app.js, is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Put a blank `div` tag inside the `Routes` tag:

```
const App = () => {
const [chamber, setChamber] = useState("")
//initialise array of present speakers
const [members, setMembers] = useState([])
    
return (
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Routes> <div></div>
                <Route path="/" element={
                    <ChamberSelector setChamber={setChamber} />}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="presence" element={
                    <PresenceList members={members} setMembers={setMembers} chamber={chamber} />}>
                </Route> 
                <Route path="body/*" element={
                    <BodyColumns members={members} chamber={chamber} setChamber={setChamber} />
                }>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
)
}
```

Comment: my friend, this doesn't work :( also it would be v helpful to explain why it might possibly work!